# Will remote resource links still work if there is no internet connection?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using some remote resources such as jQuery and icons which are linked like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Would it still work if there is no internet connection? This is my assignment so when I'm doing presentation I need to open the local .html files and maybe don't have any internet connection. I'm concerned that some of the function and icons that referenced from the online library will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the page before you lose your internet connection the files will be cached by the browser. This isn't a 100% foolproof approach, but if you test it beforehand it might work out.

Another idea is to manually save the web page locally using your browser (ctrl/cmd-s). Your browser should download all resources and put them in a folder alongside the HTML file. You can then open that file and have full functionality.

The best approach is probably what was mentioned in a comment: Download the resources and host them locally. You can grab the source code for each of those files and save them, then link to them in your document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No,
You can either download them locally and link them to your files, or you can just rely on the browser's cache, once you go to any website that uses external libraries, those libraries gets downloaded to your browser's cache so that it doesn't have to go look for them online each time you visit a website, but I really don't recommend that in case your cache got deleted.

Other than that, Yes you need internet connection.